# How to compute number of days between the entered years

Tags: lisp

How can I get the number of days between the given years, should I use loops?

Here's what I have now

```
(princ "Enter starting year: ")
(defparameter w (read))
(princ "Enter ending year: ")
(defparameter x (read))
(defun print-list (w x)
      (format t "Starting year: ~a ~%" (list w))
      (format t "Ending year: ~a ~%" (list x)))

(terpri)

(if(> x w)
   (format t "Number of year/s: ~a ~%"(- x w))
   (format t "Number of year/s: ~a ~%"(- w x)))
```

I'm trying to compute the days between years but the output was always failed.

Comment: FYI there's a whole book about calendrical calculations in Lisp! https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/calendar-book/index.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple set of functions to perform the calculation is the following:

```
 (defun leap-year-p (year)
   "return t if year is a leap-year, nil otherwise"
   (or (and (zerop (mod year 4))
            (not (zerop (mod year 100))))
       (zerop (mod year 400))))

 (defun days-of (year)
   "return the number of days of a certain year"
   (if (leap-year-p year) 365 366))

 (defun days-between (start-year end-year)
   "return the number of days between start-year (included)
    and end-year (excluded)"
   (when (<= start-year end-year)
     (loop for year from start-year below end-year sum (days-of year)))
```

A few examples of call:

```
CL-USER> (days-between 2020 2022)
731
CL-USER> (days-between 1820 1999)
65470
CL-USER> (days-between 2020 2020)
0
CL-USER> (days-between 1980 1890)
NIL
```

You can use these function to solve your problem.